# SQL Server Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int but haven't reached max of int

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm working with a table that has a PK with data type INT. The column has "Identity Increment" is set 1 and "Identity Seed" set to 1.

I'm trying to do an insert and getting the following error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

When I run the following to see what the Max id is I get is 1702747645:

```
SELECT Max(Id) FROM Log_Records
```

Int is suppose to have a cap of 2,147,483,647, so I'm wondering why I may be getting this error?

Comment: Your query can be improved. `SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Log_Records ORDER BY Id DESC` or `SELECT Max(Id) FROM Log_Records` would both be better than what you've written. Also, it's hard to say what might be wrong with your INSERT, because you've not shown the SQL you're using to do so.

Comment: Just changed it thanks, result stays the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)`('Log_Records', NORESEED);`

This will report the current identity value in the specified table.  The next identity value is not necessary sequential with the maximum value in the table, for instance if you have transactions that have rolled back.

Comment: Great query thanks. This was the output:                                    Checking identity information: current identity value '2147483647', current column value '1702747645'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. So the value is lower than the int cap, but I guess the next increment value doesn't consider the max but what sequential number it's up to?

Comment: `current identity value '2147483647'` indicates that the next value inserted will overflow the INT.

Some more details on IDENTITY column behaviors here as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx